# Use jdk virtually

Tags: 12.04, java, jdk

I have installed ubuntu 12-04 virtually using oracle virtual box. I have installed jdk on windows. Is it possible to use the same jdk for ubuntu or i will have to install jdk seperatley for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows executables don't run natively on Linux platform. You can try to execute them with `wine` once you have shared the JDK directory of Windows with the Virtual Machine, but that'd again require you to install `wine` on the Ubuntu VM, so why not install the `OpenJDK` from **Ubuntu Software centre** or the [Oracle's JDK for Linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html) instead in Ubuntu?